# Deleted AWS resources created by federated login user

Tags: amazon-web-services, federated

As per my use-case, I give temporary access to federated users to play with aws resources. After a period of 30 minutes, I need to delete all the resources created by the user. I tried to use lambda function to pull cloudtrail logs to find resources created and delete them. But under some circumstances, it is failing on some occasions and not deleting resources. Need a better workaround to delete resources created on the fly by federated users.